# create linearlayout programmatically android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to create a news layout and update it contents through database. because I don't have any information about number of news, so I must use For loop to create suitable template. I designed my sample template. Now I wanna to know, how I can created it with linear layout pragmatically.

[image]

Comment: You don't have to do it programatically, you can use ListView or RecyclerView for this. It's also much more efficient if you have a lot of entries in your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a bordered_green_background.xml and put this into it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#A8CF8B"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#051014"/>

</shape>
```

bordered_blue_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#9CC2E6"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#4C5058"/>

</shape>
```

bordered_blue_background2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#8EA9DC"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#051014"/>
</shape>
```

demo_liinear_layout.xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bordered_background_blue"
    android:text="Date"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.75"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bordered_background_blue_2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/tvTopic"
        android:text="topic"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bordered_green_background"
        android:id="@+id/tvContent"
        android:text="content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your activity do something like this

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.demo_linear_layout, null, false);
TextView tvContent = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
```

Now do something with it, but honestly go with the ListView or RecyclerView... this is way less efficient.

Note... I failed on the borders, but that is not the question... :)

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response, but there is some error in my project: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/bordered_background_blue').

Comment: Never blindly copy/paste another man's code. Now check your drawables' file names.

Comment: You have to create it. I have put it's source to it.